# Why does adding extra arrow function parentheses resolve an infinite loop problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on my project using react but I encountered a problem with using setState hook.

Here is my code:

```
//state and handle function

const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
const handleStep = (index)  => {
        setActiveStep(index);
}

//return component (I'm using mui)

return (
            <Stepper nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
                {steps.map((label, index) => (
                    <Step key={label} completed={false}>
                        <StepButton color="inherit" onClick={handleStep(index)}>
                            {label}
                        </StepButton>
                    </Step>
                ))}
            </Stepper>

    );
```

With this code page enters infinite loop and the page doesn't show up. But if I add an extra parentheses to handlestep function:

```
//added extra parantheses
const handleStep = (index) => () => {
        setActiveStep(index);
    }
```

It doesn't enter infinite loop and everything seems working.
Does adding parentheses to arrow functions changes functionality or is it a MUI component bug?

Comment: Like pointed out in the answer your executing the function there and then, rather than when `onClick` is called, you can do what the answer says, but in fairness the way you have done it is fine too, you basically created a function closure on index that returns a function.  Although it should be -> `const handleStep = (index) => () => {`

Comment: @Keith yeah it was index with paranthesis first, but I wrote it in wrong order

Comment: One parenthesis. Two parenthes*es*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling function instead of passing.

Change this

```
<StepButton color="inherit" onClick={handleStep(index)}>
```

Into this

```
<StepButton color="inherit" onClick={() => handleStep(index)}>
```